# .Net Core - Entity Framework - MySQL > UseMysql not found

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to build a simple .NET Core webapi with Entity Framework as ORM and MySQL as database backend.

The problem is that I cannot use the UseMysql method in the `ConfigureServices` method my Startup class:

[image: VS Code]

It looks like I need something more at the using section.

These are the relevant dependencies:

```
"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore":"7.0.6-ir31",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools":"1.0.0-preview1-final"
```

and I've also added this as a tool:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools":"1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add some more usings:

```
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

With these two I was able to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

For me what helped is to add the fully qualified name.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySQL(....)

Maybe it helps!